# Как мониторить постоянно интернет соединение?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно постоянно проверять подключение к интернету.
Сначала проверяется после выполняется метод и если интернет оборвался ( делать проверку что интернет есть ) продолжать выполнять метод.

Есть такой код:

```
 public static bool HasConnection()
 {
     try
     {
         using (var client = new WebClient())
         using (var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
     catch
     {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Если я засуну данный код в цикл `while(HasConnection)`, то он сильно жрёт ресурсы. Программа немного тормозит.

Подскажите как можно сделать нормальный мониторинг интернет соединения?

Comment: Если у вас опрос без задержки, например Thread.Sleep(), то ее нужно добавить. Нету смысла в таком частом опросе.

Comment: а в чем смысл так делать? То есть, зачем проверять соединение? Если вы какие то запросы отправляете в интернет, то они сами отвалятся, когда интернет пропадет. А точное время пропажи интернета вы все равно не узнаете. К тому же, сеть может быть настроена так, что часть сайтов доступна, а часть - нет. Например, если когда-нибудь гугл в вашем регионе забанят - что вы делать будете?

Comment: `то он сильно жрёт ресурсы` `тормозит` Потому что такую проверку если и делать, то делать как минимум асинхронно, либо вообще в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score 3):

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

    //Creating a function that uses the API function...
    public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
    {
        int Desc;
        return InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0);
       //Можно разобрать параметр и вернуть более детальную информацию.
    }
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetconnectedstate

Ну а про то, что не надо мониторить непрерывно уже писали.

Comment: На EnSO написано, что он лишь показывает воткнут кабель или нет.

Comment: @iluxa1810 правильно писали (наверное). Но это о возвращаемом значении. А вот параметр дает больше инфы.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какой параметр можно разобрать? И что мне делать с данным кодом? если я повешу его в цикле в отдельном потоке он будет проверят соединение? или только если пользователь отключил соединение?  На msdn написано что он : *Извлекает подключенное состояние локальной системы.*

Comment: Параметр desc. Значения по ссылке. Проверяет, естественно, при вызове функции. В каком потоке - не имеет значения. Как часто её вызывать - решайте сами.

Comment: Даже по вашей ссылке четко написано `A return value of TRUE from InternetGetConnectedState indicates that at least one connection to the Internet is available. It does not guarantee that a connection to a specific host can be established.` (дословно: `Возвращает true если доступно хотя бы одно подключение к интернету. Это не гарантирует доступ к определенному хосту.`). Я бы лично не доверил такому методу столь серьезную проверку. ИМХО, надежней будет взять ответ сервера при отправке запроса, либо сделать пинг и на его основе уже решать, отправлять нам запрос или нет...