# Как делать проверку на интернет соединение по таймерам?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как можно проверить интернет соединение в цикле или по таймерам.

Имеется метод отправки на почту файла, так вот если интернет отключился сделать проверку на интернет соединение каждые 20 - 40 сек ( мин )

```
public static bool InternetConnector()
{
  try
  {
     using (webClient.OpenRead("http://google.com/"))
     {
        return true;
     }
  }
  catch { return false; }
}
```

И способ отправки:

```
public static void SendFiles
{
   // тут сделать проверку с циклом
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
       client.UploadFile("host", "POST", "C:\\MyFiles.rar");
   }
   // допустим если интернет отключён делать проверку! и после вкл запускать метод снова.
}
```

В случае обрыва интернет соединения метод больше не сработает, как сделать слежку за интернет соединением во время отправки, и если интернет отсутствует  сделать проверку по таймеру или ещё что-то где будет каждые пол минуты проверяться.

P.S: Framework 4.0 какие есть доступные методы чтобы контролировать соединение с интернетом ?

Comment: ну, то, что будет доступ к google, не гарантирует, что ваш сайт, куда вы шлете письма, работает. Почему бы просто не пытаться слать письма по таймеру, до тех пор, пока не отправится или не превысит максимальное количество попыток?

Comment: Самое лучшее - отправить данные и смотреть на реакцию сервера (его ответ) и уже это обрабатывать. А "пинговать" сервер - это лишний запрос и не всегда эффективно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912609/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?rq=1 Все уже придумали до нас..

Comment: @tym32167, не обязательно гугл, будет тот сервер куда отправляется файл. Слать письма по таймеру? Не уловил смысл, мне нужно просто чекать интернет соединение и если оно есть отправить файл один раз, после выход из цикла окончательно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Можно пример?

Comment: Ну вы хотите проверять доступность сайта для чего? Чтобы выслать письмо, верно? Почему бы вместо поверки сайта просто не пытаться выслать что вам нужно, пока оно не вышлется?

Answer (score 0):

```
  NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged;

 private void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckForInternetConnection())
            {
                // Интернет доступен
            }
        }
        public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                using (client.OpenRead("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: А объяснить можете? Как мне это использовать? Ну из кода я понял что мы подписываемся на событие NetworkChange. Но как сделать если интернет не доступен дальнейшие действия что делать? как проверять по этому способу?!